# ClassNotFoundException on com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I am migrating project from jBoss-eap-5.1 to jboss-eap-6.0. I have defined jersey jars in the modules directory of jboss as follows:

```
com
|_jersey
  |_jersey-core
  |_jersey-client
  |_jersey-server
  |_jersey-servlet
```

In my project .pom file i defined the jars as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to deploy, I get the following error on ServletContainer class:

```
13:03:29,908 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApiEar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."ApiService-2.
0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."ApiEar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."ApiService-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE
: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "ApiService-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "ApiEar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]

        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer from [Modu
le "deployment.ApiEar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.ApiService-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:295)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:160)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:109)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]

        ... 5 more
```

Initially, I was getting this error when I did not define jersey-servlet, but I did some searching, and presumably, jersey-servlet.jar is the one that contains that class. However, that did solve the error.

Comment: AS7/JEE6 should already have everything you need for JAX-RS, unless you use some jersey-specific apis. I would first try to get rid of jersey and migrate to JEE6/JAX-RS.

Comment: @tair thanks for suggestion, but that is not an option. There are literally hundreds services running using jersey, no way to migrate now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding this dependencies into my manifest.mf file. In my .pom file I added the build plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
         <archive>
             <manifestEntries>
                  <Dependencies>com.jersey.jersey-server,com.jersey.jersey-client,com.jersey.jersey-json</Dependencies>
             </manifestEntries>
         </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

that added references to the needed .jar files in my manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I believe this was implemented in jersey in version 10. That is when big overhaul of library happened

Comment: yes, that is what I found out. Here is the link talking about Servlet in 1.10 http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.10/user-guide.html#d4e1721