# ClassNotFoundException when trying to deploy war

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jersey

I am getting the following error when I deploy to jboss.

I appreciate that the error should tell me everything I need to know - The class can not be found therefore I am missing a jar.

```
  16:29:48,377 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."swipedserver-1.0.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."swipedserver-1.0.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "swipedserver-1.0.war"
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.swipedserver-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
            at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:287)
            at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:152)
            at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:103)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
            ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.swipedserver-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
            at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:285)
            ... 8 more
```

However, if you look at my pom the values are clearly in there. I have tried with various jersey versions up to the most recent 1.81 however still no joy

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>swipedserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>swipedserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.p12</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>core</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ninja-squad</groupId>
            <artifactId>DbSetup</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**EDIT**

If i change my pom to include

```
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Dependencies>com.jersey.jersey-server,com.jersey.jersey-client</Dependencies>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
```

and my manifest to look like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: jersey-server.jar, jersey-client.jar
```

Then i get the following exception - which is a little different

```
17:03:56,202 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.swipedserver-1.0.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.swipedserver-1.0.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.swipedserver-1.0.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.jersey.jersey-server:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1030) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1386) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1414) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Did you check if it makes it to your war file? Is it the right jar?

Comment: try putting the dependency for `jersey-server` at the top of dependency list to avoid the mentioned version being ignored. Check the generated war file for this jar as well

Comment: yes just checked - the jar is in the war file under `WEB-INF/LIB`

Comment: also try adding the dependencies to your manifest as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031697/classnotfoundexception-on-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletcontainer

Comment: what would actually go in the manifest then? i have changed the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

ok so when deploying to jboss you need to change the approach for starting the sever

this is exactly what i used http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/

and it works perfectly - specifically

```
package com.mkyong.app;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import com.mkyong.rest.MessageRestService;

public class MessageApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MessageApplication() {
        singletons.add(new MessageRestService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

along with the webxml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mkyong.app.MessageApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```